# Creating health and score for game development

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Below is the code. I'm trying to add score and health to my game..I am quite new to this.. The initial score is not appearing.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");    
canvas.width=1000;    
canvas.height=500;    
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");    
var health = 10;

function healthDisplay() {                           
                        ctx.font = "bold 14px Arial";    
                        ctx.fillText("remaining life:"+health, 80, 20);
                }
```

Could anyone help please?

Comment: Your code worked for me... Are you sure you called healthDisplay() ? Also, is the code above in a script tag above or below the canvas tag?

Comment: Check the Javascript console (in the developer tools) for errors.

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex. Yep, the code works fine and you've spotted the 2 likely solitions -- you should post it as an answer. **thelightdom:** When you wrap code inside a `function healthDisplay(){...}` its not automatically executed. To actually run the code, you must "call" the function like this `healthDisplay();`. Secondly, you must wait for the webpage to load before trying to execute any code. To wait, you wrap your code in `script` tags and then wrap your code in `window.onlonad`. [For example](https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/y1scct2j/).